# how to create an encrypted s3 bucket while creating new s3 bucket with boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, botocore

how to create encrypted s3 bucket while creating new s3 bucket with boto3

I know how to encrypt an existing bucket. But, is there any way to encrypt while creating it via boto3?

Answer (score 0):

You don't techinically encrypt any buckets, only can provide default encryption for objects if they don't specify their own. And you can't do this why you create a bucket. You **need  a separate API call** for that: [put_bucket_encryption](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_encryption).